# Google oauth2 decline permission with extension... how to re-prompt?

Tags: google-oauth

In a chrome extension with oauth2 in manifest.json, the extension prompts originally for access to the various scopes (gmail.readonly, etc.)

For testing, I declined, but now I'd like to grant permission. How can I force the extension to re-prompt for oauth scope permissions? I've tried removing and re-installing the extension, but it will not prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the solution, but it works now. I was still seeing the missing token in chrome://identity-internals/ It would not go away until I ran chrome://restart